# Auto Uninstall WinRT App after Debugging Stopped

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I want to automatically uninstall a WinRT app after it has finished debugging. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Remove-AppxPackage to do the uninstall. I don't know if there's a post-debugging trigger you can hook to do this.

Remove-AppxPackage => http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856038.aspx